# Как сделать check_box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Есть модель User (devise), в ней чекбокс - при регистрации пользователь должен соглашаться с Правилами. Чекбокс в форму я запилил, но почему-то rails не видит поставленную галочку и все равно пишет что Terms must be accepted. Я где-то накосячил или в самой форме неправильно чекбокс добавил?

Модель:

```
validates :terms, acceptance: true
```

Схема:

```
t.boolean  "terms",                  default: false
```

Users_controller:

```
private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :phone, :address, :terms)
    end
```

Application_controller:

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, 
                                        keys: [:phone, :address, :terms])
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, 
                                        keys: [:phone, :address, :terms])
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, 
                                        keys: [:phone, :address, :terms])
    end
```

Форма:

```
<%= f.label :terms, "Правила" %>
<%= f.check_box :terms %>
```

Comment: Гляньте в логах, что приходит в `params` этого запроса. И решительно непонятно, зачем хранить эту галочку в базе.

Comment: Вроде все нормально с самим чекбоксом, при нажатой галке "terms"=>"1", при не нажатой "terms"=>"0". Во вьюхе Terms must be accepted и рендерит new.